# python selenium webdrive con un svg cerrar banner

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, svg, xpath

website https://www.radarbox.com/@35.38300,-77.41146,z4

los abre con selenium import webdriver todo bien

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://www.radarbox.com/@35.38300,-77.41146,z4')

while True:
  pass
```

[image: website]

[image: website inspeccionar]

como puedo cerrar ese banner

Answer (score 0):

selenium tiene una funcion llamada `click()` la cual permite "pulsar" un elemento en la pagina.

Teniendo eso en cuenta se me ocurre que si buscas ese elemento y lo cliqueas se cerrara. Asi es como se usaria:

```
cerrarBoton= driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".content > svg")
cerrarBoton.click()
```

Ahi buscaria el boton con su nombre (puede ser id o clase) y en la siguiente linea lo pulsara, cerrandolo.

PD: `.content > svg` por si no estas familiarizado con el css, ahi accederias al div con nombre de clase `content` y de ahi a su hijo que es el svg. Seria mejor poner directamente el nombre de la clase o id del svg pero dado que no tiene lo puedes solucionar asi.

Un saludo, espero que te sirva de ayuda!

Comment: muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

NO se pero a mi la ventana se cierra cuando el mouse oprime la x de cerrar esa ventana, y siempre la ventana abre en la misma posición lo cual es bastante mas fácil de cerrar, solamente debes mover el mouse a la misma posición en todas las veces y oprimir el click del mouse, con una resolución de pantalla de 1920x1080, mueve el mouse a 1284,151 y oprime el boton del mouse, y la ventana se cierra sin ningún problema, no pide ninguna conformación.

Esto se puede hacer con un simple programa de tkinter que mueva el mouse a una posicion especifica y genere el evento <1> en esa posicion del mouse.